# Where is Rain's tavern located?

Tags: silver

Reviving a very old game: I just bought [Silver](http://www.gog.com/game/silver) on [gog.com](http://gog.com), because I wanted to play this classic of my childhood (may or not be a classic of yours).

I've killed the giant at the Ice Caves and acquired the Orb of Ice, then proceeded to visit the professor in Gno. He told about a necromancer that has a submarine that will allow travelling to Spires.

I remember from playing the game when I was little that there was a tavern in Rain, where there was a old man that knew the password for the bell-locked gate which grants access to lower Rain, however I can't seem to find it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken straight from the wiki found [here](http://www.the-spoiler.com/RPG/Infogrames/silver1.3.html), the tavern is in Upper Rain. In order to get to through the gate to Upper Rain, do the following:

- You need to travel to David's House (use the map).
- From there on move to the right and then upwards. You'll enter a
  screen with a gorge
- kill all the enemies and move to the right (to Vivienne's cottage).
- Enter the house and take her with you.
- Walk back to the gorge and move to the left.
- You'll meet the paranoid mayor of Rain. Once you scared his guards off, he'll drop the city key.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: After a long time running around, I decided going to Vivienne's place and complete that area, to realize how to get to the tavern. Either way, may this help the future readers!